# How to change a value in a dataframe/series in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, series

I was trying to look up the tickers for Nasdaq 100 companies and got it from wikipedia

```
nasdaq100 = pd.read_html('https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASDAQ-100')[4][0][1:]
print(nasdaq100)
```

Which gives me:

```
1             ATVI
2             ADBE
3             ALXN
4             ALGN
5      GOOG, GOOGL
...            ...
100           XLNX
```

However, I would like to get only GOOG. How do I replace "GOOG, GOOGL" with just "GOOG"? This occurs multiple times throughout the list and I would like to get the text before the comma only.

```
for ticker in nasdaq100:
    if ',' not in ticker:
        continue
    else:
        nasdaq100[ticker] = nasdaq100[ticker].split(',')[0]
```

With the last line I want to update the series in this particular position with only the part that comes before the comma (","). But this is where I get an error:

```
KeyError: 'GOOG, GOOGL'
```

Any help out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to use the same function across a whole series, you can do that with `.apply`:

```
nasdaq100.apply(lambda x: x.split(",")[0])

1       ATVI
2       ADBE
3       ALXN
4       ALGN
5       GOOG
6       AMZN
```

Comment: Ok I used: nasdaq100 = nasdaq100.apply(lambda x: x.split(",")[0]) --> that did the job